# beanshell decimal variables with proper value out

Tags: java, jmeter

How do I write beanshell script to get complete decimal value?

My code is:

```
valueput = 0.00000001;

Double i = new Double(vars.get("valueput"));

Double = i * 2;

vars.put("test", Double.toString(i));
```

Currently the above code is giving a value 1.0E-7.

I want the exact actual value 0.00000001.

Please let me know.

Comment: `System.out.println(new BigDecimal("0.00000001").toPlainString());`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class instead of Double. Example code:

   ```
   vars.put("valueput", "0.00000001");

   BigDecimal i = new BigDecimal(vars.get("valueput"));

   BigDecimal Double = i * 2;

   vars.put("test", Double.toPlainString());

   log.info(vars.get("test"));
   ```
2. Use [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) instead of Beanshell (this is optional, but [highly recommended](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black))

   Demo:

   [image: JMeter Groovy double math operations]

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T.